# Google app engine show image

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp, servlets

I've a problem showing an image grabbed from the DataStore in Google App Engine Java.

Servlet code:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws IOException, ServletException
{
    String type=request.getParameter("type");

    if(type != null)
    {
        if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("showImage"))
        {
            Blob blob = this.retrieveImage();
            response.setContentType("image/jpg");
            response.getOutputStream().write(blob.getBytes());  
        }
    }
}

private Blob retrieveImage()
{
    GetImageQuery query = new GetImageQuery ();
    List<ImageData> listImages=query.getImages();

    Blob blobImage = listImages.get(0).getImage();
    return blobImage;
}
```

Image src url used:

```
<img src="/image?type=showImage" />
```

Something's probably missing, just can't figure out what. I've debugged it and the code is run and the blob contains data but an image is simply not showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right MIME type for JPEG images is `image/jpeg` and not `image/jpg` (see this [reference](http://www.w3schools.com/media/media_mimeref.asp)) and it seems that some web browsers don't accept `image/jpg`.

You can try the same code with `response.setContentType("image/jpeg");`.